# How to pass value to Angular $interval function

Tags: angularjs

## Condition

I have an array of HTML element constructed using ngRepeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons">Name: {{ person.name }}. Age {{ person.age }}</li>
```

In my controller I am trying to update (random) the person's "age" dynamically using Angular $interval.

```
$scope.persons = [
  {name: "John Doe", age: 30},
  {name: "Peter Parker", age: 21},
  {name: "Clark Kent", age: 45},
  {name: "John Wayne", age: 33}
];    
var promiseOfYouth = [];
$scope.makeYoung = function() {
    //since persons are store in array object. 
    //loop persons to update dynamically each person age
    for(var x = 0; x < $scope.persons.length; x++) {
        //check age randomizer already running
        if ( angular.isDefined(promiseOfYouth[x]) ) return;
        //make them young!
        promiseOfYouth[x] = $interval(function() {
          console.log('x value in $interval function: '+x);
          try {
            $scope.persons[x].age = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 17 + 1)) + 17;
          } catch(err) {
              console.log('"$scope.persons['+x+'].age" is not valid. Error message:'+err.message);  
          }
        }, 100, 50);
    }
}
```

## Problem

In the makeYoung function the "x" value always return "4"

## Question

How do I passed value of "x" (in this case it should 0,1,2,3) into the $interval function?
For further details please take a look at my jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gilacode/fz2k9uhj/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a classical JavaScript gotcha. You need to have x in a new scope to make this work. Otherwise, all the closures use the value of the same x variable, which is 4 at the end of the loop.

See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeay8zqz/)

```
function makePersonYoung(x) {
    //check age randomizer already running
    if ( angular.isDefined(promiseOfYouth[x]) ) return;
    //make them young!
    promiseOfYouth[x] = $interval(function() {
        $scope.persons[x].age = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 17 + 1)) + 17;
    }, 100, 50);
}


$scope.makeYoung = function() {
    //since persons are store in array object. 
    //loop persons to update dynamically each person age
    for(var x = 0; x < $scope.persons.length; x++) {
        makePersonYoung(x);
    }
}
```

This solution has the added advantage of making the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle example and explanation. JS closure is till something I find it quite hard to understand but this gotcha has definitely help me to see it from different perspective. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [quirk](http://www.2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-closures.html) of javascript. That blog post suggests several solutions. Copy the x variable as an immediately executing function:

```
(function(x2) {promiseOfYouth[x2] = $interval(function() {
          console.log('x value in $interval function: '+x2);
          try {
            $scope.persons[x2].age = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 17 + 1)) + 17;
          } catch(err) {
              console.log('"$scope.persons['+x2+'].age" is not valid. Error message:'+err.message);  
          }
        }, 100, 50)}(x);
```

Or bind the the function

```
promiseOfYouth[x] = $interval(function(x2) {
      console.log('x value in $interval function: '+x2);
      try {
        $scope.persons[x2].age = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 17 + 1)) + 17;
      } catch(err) {
          console.log('"$scope.persons['+x2+'].age" is not valid. Error message:'+err.message);  
      }
    }.bind(null, x), 100, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog post :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can inject it like a parameter

```
 promiseOfYouth[x] = $interval(function(x) {
          console.log('x value in $interval function: '+x);
          try {
            $scope.persons[x].age = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 17 + 1)) + 17;
          } catch(err) {
              console.log('"$scope.persons['+x+'].age" is not valid. Error message:'+err.message);  
          }
        }, 100, 50);
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fz2k9uhj/11/)